# jQuery Function vs. hardcode. Function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question with jQuery. Can one not pass the id's to a javascript function containing jQuery with certain events?

For example, `load_dl`l works perfectly. I'm struggling to get `update_dll` to work properly.

```
 //Create values for drop down list
var empType = ['Sales Associate', 'New Hire Sales Associate', 'Post-Hire Graduation', 'Senior Supervisor'];
//initialize values
load_ddl(empType, 'empTypeddl');
update_dll('empTypedll', 'empType');
//Populate drop down list function
function load_ddl(arr, id) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $('<option/>').val(arr[i]).html(arr[i]).appendTo('#' + id);
    }
}
//Update Function
function update_ddl(source_id, target_id) {
    $('#' + source_id).change(function() {
        alert($('#' + source_id + ' option:selected').attr('value'));
    });
}
```

If I simplify it down to it's most basic form it works though. Is it possible to pass the id's?

```
$('#empTypeddl').change(function() {
     alert($('#empTypeddl option:selected').attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: Please from now on, use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`.

Comment: it might make more sense to just assign all the #empTypeddl type objects a class and use the same .change function for all instead of writing a new one for every instance?

Comment: I really didn't understand what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing in the source_id as even data like so:

```
//Update Function
function update_ddl(source_id, target_id) {
    $('#' + source_id).change({source_id: source_id}, function(event) {
        alert($('#' + event.data.source_id + ' option:selected').attr('value'));
    });
}
```

This creates a data property and appends it to the event object.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code:

```
function update_ddl(source_id, target_id) {
```

should be:

```
function update_dll(source_id, target_id) {
```

Comment: I would say THAT typo isn't the problem, if the function does work fine when he hard-codes the value instead of passing it. Clearly he does call the function correctly, so he must have made a typo when posting.
I think the fact that he passes in 'empTypedll', but hard-codes 'empTypeddl' is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used native javascript to get the object and i assigned to a variable 'source'

```
  function update_ddl(source_id, target_id) {

    var source = document.getElementById('source_id');
    source.change(function() {
        alert('$("#'+ source_id + ' option:selected").attr("value")');
    });  

 }
```

Comment: Native elements don't have jQuery methods.

Comment: Cant we use both at the same time?

Comment: You can use `$(source).change` if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
update_dll('empTypedll', 'empType');
```

should be

```
update_ddl('empTypeddl', 'empType');
```